# Is Multi Master Single Slave possible in mySQL DB?

Tags: linux, mysql, php

[image]

Consider my above Image. I am using Linux Dedicated Server, PHP & mySQL. Is this architecture is possible or not? If possible please explain the details. If not possible, please suggest me another best way to accomplish the model. If you think that PostGres is best for this model, also suggest me.

Please help me asap. Thanks in advance. (If you have to know more, please make a comment.)

**Edit:**
I am going to setup a web application where I will have a huge traffic. My each Station will generate a huge traffic. So I am planning to store individual station's data in different mySQL servers. Staion DBs are that kind of DBs. Now as I have to generate reports based on all the Stations of my client, I am planning to consolidate all the databases together. For load balancing I am using more than one setups where multiple Stations will reside in each Setup. Now I want to run a cron job on each Station DB to consolidate the Setup Consolidated DB. Now Setup Consolidate DB will be replicated in the Central Server's individual Setup_Consolidated DBs. I now run a cron job again to Consolidate these DBs and finally I am able to make the necessary reports of my Client.

I want to know, if I am wrong in model design or if you have better idea. Please let me know in details with the Techno you suggest.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been and always will be a controversial issue. The answer is both yes and no.

You will have to setup multiple servers, some with real data and some with BLACKHOLE storage engine tables only into order to fanagle or mimic true multimaster, single slave. In reality, multimaster is impossible in the explicit sense since MySQL only uses [CHANGE MASTER TO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/change-master-to.html) to establish replication from a sinlge master to a single slave. MySQL has no current internal infrastructure to support slaving from multiple servers.

I had addressed something like this twice in another question someone posted in two different forums in the StackExchange.

First URL : [MySQL in star topology](https://serverfault.com/questions/264374/mysql-in-star-topology/264444#264444)

Second URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273043/mysql-in-star-topology/5784578#5784578

You can jerry rig something in order to have multimaster, single slave. Maintenance would be a nightmare, but doable nontheless.

Enjoy the reading. Hope this helps.

Comment: For your second URL, could you please explain more about **IMPORT PROCESS** ? I am not able to understand properly this part. It is also very much helpful to me and others if you can provide a picture of the Model. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do have any pictures but the book "High Performance MySQL : Optimization, Backups, Replication and More" (http://www.amazon.com/dp/0596101716) on Pages 373-375 has the pictures you may need.