# How to slave real-time data from two MySQL sources merging in to one MySQL destination?

Tags: mysql, database-mirroring, master-slave, tungsten

I have two different MySQL instances that I would like to 'slave' to a third instance.
(so I can do easy joins on the third instance)

eg.

```
mysql1> show databases
db1
db2

mysql2> show databases
db3
db4

mysql3> show databases
db1
db2
db3
db4
```

I've looked at maatkit [(percona toolkit)](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/) pt-table-sync but people say it can corrupt data.
(It apparent removes and re-adds data to generate inserts)

pt-archiver sort of works for 'snapshots', but db1 is approximately 6GB and copying the whole thing over is a lot more data than really needed. The real time updates are only about 100MB a day.

The natural concept to me would be to allow mysql3 to run as a replica slave of BOTH mysql1 and mysql2, but that doesn't seem to be an option in MySQL

[Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) seems to allow for this type of data sync, but it seems a bit unwieldy to configure and I'm concerned about reliability.

Does anyone have other solutions they've used for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

By design, one mysqld process cannot simultaneously listen to two different Masters.

The CHANGE MASTER TO command only allows you to set one Master as a source to read.

In order to emulate this, you would have to alternate between the two Masters programmatically. How do you do that ?

[I described in StackOverflow how to Connect a Slave Manually to different Masters where each Master was a Laptop and the Slave was a Central Computer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784578/491757)

Here is the basic idea

- Master M1
- Master M2
- Slave S1

Setup Replication of M1 to S1 and then M2 to S1 like this

- 1) Have S1 run CHANGE MASTER TO with M1 as the Source
- 2) START SLAVE;
- 3) Run Replication for a Little While
- 4) STOP SLAVE;
- 5) Have S1 run CHANGE MASTER TO with M2 as the Source
- 6) START SLAVE;
- 7) Run Replication for a Little While
- 8) STOP SLAVE;
- 9) Go Back to Step 1

Each time you switch from one Master to another, you must record two values from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G`

1. Relay_Master_Log_file
2. Exec_Master_Log_Pos

These two values represent the last SQL Statement that came from the Master and was is next to be executed on the Slave.

There is one major caution : As long as M1 and M2 are updating mutually exclusive databases, this algorithm should be just fine.

Believe it or not, [I addressed a question like this in ServerFault back in May 2011. I actually explained how to emulate true multimaster/single slave using the BLACKHOLE Storage Engine based on the book "High Performance MySQL".](https://serverfault.com/a/270255/69271)

Comment: Any experience using Tungsten? How is your method related to the BLACKHOLE storage engine?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a good read-made tool to do this. pt-table-sync doesn't work exactly as you've been told (I wrote it ;) but it's not the right solution.  I have seen its bidirectional syncing functionality used to reconcile servers to a central source after being intentionally disconnected and updated, but this isn't the right solution for what you need.

I don't normally give sales pitches on topics like this, but this is honestly a case where I'd engage Percona to develop a new tool for you. Some people have written little scripts that suit their personal scenarios, but a high-quality solution for general use doesn't exist yet, and isn't really that hard. The main thing is that you need formal testing, and Percona Toolkit's components are already 90% of the way to what you need -- it just needs a little bit of glue between them. You could do this yourself, of course, but why make a square wheel and end up maintaining it yourself and discovering all of its bugs when you least desire it?

That said (end sales pitch, sorry) -- the solution I'd suggest should avoid blackhole tables and go with simpler, less troublesome techniques.  (Yeah -- I wrote High Performance MySQL, too.  I know. Back then I hadn't seen as many problems with blackhole tables as I have today.)  It should do roughly what Rolando suggests, but there are some subtleties. For example, it shouldn't let the I/O thread stream a bunch of data from the master, getting far ahead of the SQL thread, then throw it all away when it round-robins to the next server. That would be really wasteful and cause a lot of impact on the master.  There are a lot of little details like this that need to be taken care of -- another that comes to mind is not switching masters when a replication-caused temporary table is in use.

Comment: You would have percona write a tool to round robin masters? Or something else altogether?  Any thoughts on Tungsten?

Comment: Yes, round-robining masters.

Tungsten is nice technology, but it replaces replication, it doesn't enhance or manage it. This might not be what you are looking for.  I don't have any reason NOT to recommend it.