# [MySQL]multiple-masters single-slave

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, database-administration

Is is possible to have a setup where multiple mysql servers (containing different databases) are replicated in a single mysql slave server ?

If yes, how to do it ?

Comment: There's some existing discussion of this at http://serverfault.com/questions/362776/how-to-slave-real-time-data-from-two-mysql-sources-merging-in-to-one-mysql-desti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using built-in MySQL replication, this is not possible.  Some workarounds have been built that will periodically execute CHANGE MASTER to sync from one database, then execute CHANGE MASTER to sync from the other (I thought this was a maatkit tool, but I can't find it).

[Tungsten Replicator](http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/) allows you to do this also - multi-source replication.

Answer (score 0):

If your design allows it, it may work, but i havent tested it
Server A - master, and with replication-do-db you may pull databases from server B
Server B - master
Server C - slave of B

Worth a shot in a test environment